# How to destroy at runtime Unity gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an application with Unity 2018.3.0f2

In the application when is running I create a popup at runtime with some images. This is the popup:
[image]

This is the GameObject:

[image]

I create at runtime the element "HelpImg(Clone)", using the following code:

```
var img = Instantiate(HelpImage, ImageHolder);
img.AddComponent<Image>();
img.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = helpimage[i].Image;
```

Now I need to remove all element "HelpImg(Clone)" from the game at runtime, but I m unable to do it. I m using the following code but it are not working at moment:

```
GameObject[] objHelpImage = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("HelpImage");
if(objHelpImage != null){
   GameObject panel = objHelpImage[0];
   Transform[] ts = panel.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
   if (ts.Length > 1)
   {
      //significa che ho altre immagini 
      for(int i = 1; i<ts.Length; i++)
      {
         Transform t = ts[i];
         Destroy(t.gameObject);
      }
   }
                }
```

Comment: you cant destroy in order, so, if you do 1-4, you destroy 1, it now becomes 1-3, so you destroy 2, and now its 1&2 no 3 and will either error or miss some.

Comment: Save them to the class field on creation, then simply delete all saved objects.

Comment: I don't understand. I want to remove all element from popup "HelpImg(Clone)" how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

in your script
GetComponentsInChildren would also get the Transfrom of the HelpImage
FindGameObjectsWithTag searched by tag, make sure tag already added in these [HelpImage].

I agree the idea of Morion which talked in comment. use referecne always give you more efficent and directly way to control your object.

if you have some specfic script(maybe called HelpImageController] in your [HelpImage] , you could get them by `popup.GetComponentInChildren<HelpImageController>()`